# Azure Web App - Cannot GET (particular path)

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, botframework

I have been trying out the [AADv2 sample](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/tree/master/Node/examples/aadv2) from BotAuth to no avail.

The error that I keep getting after I select the button on the action card is that either a `HTTP 500 internal server error`, or `Cannot GET /botauth/aadv2`. When I check if the root web page or the messaging endpoint is working or not, I get the same error - either `Cannot GET /` or `Cannot GET \api\messages`. The root page I have been trying to get to is https://(botname).azurewebsites.net

May I know what steps I can take to resolve this issue? I have tried to Google the error, but to no avail. Please let me know if you need more information!

Comment: The last two routes you provided are not setup for those methods. The server only exposes the route [`'/api/messages'`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/blob/master/Node/examples/aadv2/app.js#L42) for `POST` methods. For `'/'`, the server doesn't expose any routes here. You can see this by looking in the code for `server.get('/', function(req, res) { ... });`, which can't be found in the file.

Comment: @StevenG.my bad, I was just poking around to see what other results I could get if i used different routes. My main concern was just the main route - `/botauth/aadv2` for the OAuth process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are test the sample directly on Azure Web Apps, there should be a few of questions we should pay attention on.

1, `const MICROSOFT_APP_ID = envx("MICROSOFT_APP_ID");
   const MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD = envx("MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD");`
we declare the environment valiable as `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword`. Please modify this sentence as

```
//bot application identity
const MICROSOFT_APP_ID = envx("MicrosoftAppId");
const MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD = envx("MicrosoftAppPassword");
```

2, And you also need to check the environment variables are set correctly in Application settings of Azure Web App, which is shown at https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/tree/master/Node/examples/aadv2#3-setup-environment-variables

3, You can leverage online code editor to develop, debug, and manage your project on Azure Web Apps.
[image]

And in the `output` column, you can see the detailed errors throwm by the application. You can leverage these info to narrow down your issue.
[image]

Tips, after you changing the application settings, it's better to restart your Azure Web App.

Comment: Hi @Gary, I followed your suggestions and am able to get pass that set of error and is now getting `Unauthorized` instead. I think I might have to look at some of my other settings. Thank you for your time and effort to craft this answer! :)